# Elastic query to find similar tags in content from different organizations

Tags: elasticsearch

I consume content sources from different organizations, which all supply metadata tags. I would like a list of terms, that are supplied by different organizations.

**A sample of data in Elasticsearch:**

```
doc1: {
    "tags":["tag1", "tag5", "tag6", "tag4"],
    "organization" : "A"
}

doc2: {
    "tags":["tag1", "tag2", "tag4"],
    "organization" : "B"
}
```

**Desired query result:**

```
{
   "tag": "tag1",
   "organization" : ["A", "B"]
},

{
   "tag": "tag4",
   "organization" : ["A", "B"]
}
```

**What i got so far**

With the suggestion below, i got a list of results containing keywords that are used by one organization, and keywords that are used by different organizations.

To clarify, this a is a part of the result:

```
     {
      "key": "someKeyWord",
      "doc_count": 66,
      "organization_list": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "Organization A",
            "doc_count": 62
          },
          {
            "key": "Organization B",
            "doc_count": 4
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "someOtherKeyword",
      "doc_count": 62,
      "organization_list": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "Organization A",
            "doc_count": 62
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Now i only want the first result, which has two buckets from the organization_list aggregation. Because that keyword is used by two different organizations.

I tried like this:

```
    "number_buckets_filter": {
        "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
                "my_var": "organization_list"
             },
             "script": "params.my_var > 1"
        }
    }
```

But that gets me an exception: "buckets_path must reference either a number value or a single value numeric metric aggregation, got: org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.terms.StringTerms"

Is there any way to filter the results? Thanks in advance for any help.

Kind regards,
Oskar uit de Bos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query to bucket first on tags and then to sub bucket on organizations

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "tags_list": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tags",
        "size": 100
      },"aggs": {
        "organization_list": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "organization",
            "size": 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

mappings

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "product": {
            "properties": {
                "tags": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "organization": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fielddata": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note - make sure the have both tags and organization as not analyzed for aggregations. also set `fielddata=true` in mappings to avoid heavy memory usages.

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction! The current query also returns keywords that are used by one organization. Is there any way to filter the results to only return tags used by different organizations?

Comment: @Oskar i did't get this' way to filter the results to only return tags used by different organizations' can you share some example?

Comment: I updated my question with a clarification, since it doesn't fit into a comment. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: yes you can filter than on min_doc count parameter for aggregation, but what all other filters you are considering here.

Comment: That won't work since the number of documents seems irrelevant. One keyword can exist in a lot of documents, but only come from one organization. I only want tags that are used by different organizations. I need the results with multiple organization buckets. Is there a minimal bucket count or something that i can use?

Comment: take a look at this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html

Comment: I tried using bucket filters, but i don't know how to apply them in on a StringTerms field. See the buttom of my original question for the exception i am getting. Could you perhaps help to apply it correctly?

Comment: you have been a great help so far, i would really appriciate your help with the result filtering. I am not able to implement the bucket filter correctly.